# PHP malformed query SQL 1064 error

Tags: php, sql

I have the following piece of PHP

```
$manufacturers_query_raw = "select manufacturers_id, manufacturers_name, manufacturers_image, date_added, last_modified from " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " order by manufacturers_name";
$manufacturers_split = new splitPageResults($HTTP_GET_VARS['page'], MAX_DISPLAY_SEARCH_RESULTS_ADMIN, $manufacturers_query_raw, $manufacturers_query_numrows);
$manufacturers_query = tep_db_query($manufacturers_query_raw);
while ($manufacturers = tep_db_fetch_array($manufacturers_query)) 
{
 if ((!isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['mID']) || (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['mID']) && ($HTTP_GET_VARS['mID'] == $manufacturers['manufacturers_id']))) && !isset($mInfo) && (substr($action, 0, 3) != 'new')) {
  $manufacturer_products_query = tep_db_query("select count(*) as products_count from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " where manufacturers_id = '" . (int)$manufacturers['manufacturers_id'] . "'");
  $manufacturer_products = tep_db_fetch_array($manufacturer_products_query);
  $mInfo_array = array_merge($manufacturers, $manufacturer_products);
  $mInfo = new objectInfo($mInfo_array);
}
```

And I get the following error on the webpage:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select manufacturers_id, manufacturers_name, manufacturers_image, date_added, la' at line 1
>
> select count(select manufacturers_id, manufacturers_name, manufacturers_image, date_added, last_modified from manufacturers order by manufacturers_name) as total

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Off topic: Don't use `$HTTP_GET_VARS`. It is obsolete (and has been obsolete for a **very** long time). Use `$_GET` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for your additional select statement within the SELECT COUNT()?

```
select count(*) as total
```

would do the same thing as:

```
select count(select manufacturers_id, manufacturers_name, manufacturers_image, date_added, last_modified from manufacturers order by manufacturers_name) as total
```

(if it were valid)

Comment: where to write that modification within php

Comment: I think you are showing us the wrong code - the query it complains about doesn't seem to be described in what you posted. Is there another query going on in the constructor for `splitPageResults()` ?

Comment: nope it doesnt seem. the function only acts on the values of $manufacturers_query_raw, $manufacturers_query_numrows

Comment: search your project for the term: "as total" .. this should show you the query which is going wrong. my guess is you have a line that looks something like: `tep_db_query("select count(" . $manufacturers_query_raw . ") as total");`